# Accessing fields in model class are always undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, constructor, getter

A have a model class:

**item.js:**

```
    exports.constructor = function constructor(field) {
        var item = new Item()
        item.field = field;
        return item
    }

    class Item {

        set field(field) {
            this._field = field
        }

        get field() {
            return this._field;
        }
    }
```

I now read the database field in a repository file, where I had inserted it.

**repository.js:**

```
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM items ", function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;

        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            console.log("## " + rows[0].field())
        }
    });
```

Going into the debugger I can see *rows[0]* is a *RowDataPacket*. If I expand the debugger view of the object I see the field has the correct string inside that was in the database as well.

**But**: *rows[0].field()* or *rows[0]._field* always are undefined if I print the variable that way. Thx 4 help!

Comment: How is the first piece of code related to the second one?

Comment: Maybe you database returns it as json, not as the javascript object? Without seeing the database code, there is not enough context to answer this question.

Comment: @JonasWilms The first piece is the model class. The second snippet s another place where the code is read from the database

Comment: @softwaresupply But you say that `rows[0]` is a `RowDataPacket`. Why would you expect it to be an `Item`? And why are you calling `.field` as a method when it is a getter property?

Comment: @reggaemuffin The connection instance is created via:  connection = mysql.createConnection(...).  The was inserted into the database with connection.query("INSERT INTO items (field) VALUES ('foo').", ....)

Comment: @Bergi The debugger shows its a RowDataPacket. If I expand the debuggers view I see the field inside the RowDataPacket (called item). But I cannot access it in code.

Comment: So, `rows[0].item.field`?

Comment: @Bergi rows[0] already is the item. var item = rows[0]. it looks like this is a JSON then as the debugger says item then i:.{
  "id": 1,
  "field": "foo"
}  . I need to extract an item out of it.

Comment: Maybe you should post a screenshot of your debugger. Maybe also contact the documentation of your database library, it's clear that the object you are getting back is not an instance of your `Item` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. The usual "getter" didnt work. I needed to to item['field'] to access the value.